# Can't get page numbers right (toc, setcounter)

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, roman

So I want the beginning of my manuscript to be numbered with roman numbers. First page is the title page then an empty page. The third page is the abstract, for which I used the \setcounter{page}{3} command, after that follows another empty page and the ToC, which is then numbered as 2. The problem is that my ToC goes over 2 pages and if I use the \setcounter command, only the second page will be set to the desired value. What can I do, to get the numbering right?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 

%title page
\begin{titlepage}
    %this was left out/ irrelevant
\end{titlepage}

\newpage % blank page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

%abstract
\renewcommand\abstractname{\large\bfseries\filcenter\uppercase{ABSTRACT}}
\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{3}

    %text

    
    \vfill
\end{abstract}
\newpage % blank page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

%table of contents
\tableofcontents %the ToC is long, 2 pages
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{page}{5}
´´´
```

Comment: It is probably better that you provide code that shows us what exactly you are doing. Generally there is no need to mess with page numbers like this, so we'd like to get a better idea about what exactly you're doing and what exactly is the end goal

Comment: Ok, so this is for a thesis. My page numbers need to follow APA  guidelines, meaning roman numbers for the things before the main text (abstract, list of figures, ...) and arabic numbers for the rest.  My main problem is, that the ToC is two pages long and the \setcounter doesn't seem to work for it, since I set only one number for 2 pages...

Comment: Your example is incomplete. There is no document class. Does the guide line tell you that you are not allowed to have a TOC of more than one page? Also adding formatting into a `\...name` macro is bad form: `\renewcommand\abstractname{\large\bfseries\filcenter\uppercase{ABSTRACT}}`

Comment: I don't know about the APA guidelines but traditionally initial page numbers are roman (starting from i), then main body with arabic page numbers (starting from 1). In the `book` class (and others like it) `\frontmatter` will set roman page numnbers and `\mainmater` will restart with arabic page numbers. No need to do lots of fiddling around.

Comment: I thought the rest of the code was not relevant. Document class is report. There is no limit to pages a ToC can have, but since LaTex does not count the empty pages, it numbers the abstract as i and the ToC as ii and iii, but it should be numbered as iii, v and vi.